# sqlcipher command line not working

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have a encrypted sqlite db and its key. (Which is generated by an android program).
However, when I open the db in command line I can not read the db.
The command line tool is installed by:

```
brew install sqlcipher
```

I open the database by:

```
sqlcipher EnDB.db
>pragma key="6b74fcd";
>select * from bizinfo;
```

It keeps telling me "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database"

However, if I open the database file with gui app sqlite database browser (which is a windows program and I run it in wine). It pops up a window for me to enter the key, with 6b74fcd as the key it successfully read the database.

[image: sqlite database browser]

As I want to automatically process the db in the future, I can not depend on the GUI.
Do you know why the command line is not working?

Comment: can you tell us where you got this version of sqlite browser from? Because the version at http://sqlitebrowser.org/ does not support encrypted databases.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa   http://valentin.dasdeck.com/xtras/sqlite_xtra/win/tools/

Comment: Thanks, also - you might want to try to decrypt the database permanently - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132477/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sqlcipher-database-file-on-command-line/25132478#25132478

Comment: how did you encrypted the db using sqlcipher? is there any tutorial? if possible please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229318/how-to-encrypt-a-sqlite-database-using-sqlcipher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved already!

after

```
pragma key="6b74fcd";
```

Call this:

```
pragma cipher_use_hmac=off;
```

Then everything works like a charm.
It seems the database is a 1.x database.

Comment: I am also getting the exact same situation but this solution unfortunately didn't work for me. How did you work out the database was V 1.x?

Comment: Use also
  PRAGMA cipher_migrate;

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to go through some trouble with a similar issue, here's what helped in my case.

After opening the database in the Terminal via

```
sqlcipher mydatabase.db
```

I made sure the compatibility was given

```
PRAGMA cipher_default_compatibility = 1;
```

Then I provided the key

```
PRAGMA key='theKey';
```

Now, I could use SQL statements like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

Obviously, make sure that things like "mydatabase.db", "theKey" and "myTable" are replaced with your individual database name, key and table name.